# Monero inception - how did bitmonero become monero?

Tags: history, core-development-team

I understand that bitmonero was one of the first CryptoNote coins, and at its inception had a different developer team, mainly [thankful_for_today](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=233561%20thankful_for_today).

Then, "the community took over" because of some disagreement and it became monero. But what does this mean? Was the project re-started with new genesis block but with the same name? Was the code just forked? What was the difference and disagreement? What exactly happened at this point in history? Many times I saw mention of this event, or series of events, but never got to understand what happened. Would be nice if it was documented somehow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Was the project re-started with new genesis block but with the same name?

No, the project was never restarted with a new genesis block. The project simply continued with a new set of stewards of the project. These stewards replaced, or more bluntly put kicked out, the old team, which was led by [thankful_for_today](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=233561%20thankful_for_today). That is, after some [discussion](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=563821.msg6362144#msg6362144) on IRC, the "move" / "takeover", in conjunction with a name change, was announced by [David Latapie](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=81999) on the [Bitcointalk forum](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=563821.msg6362485#msg6362485). The stewards, better known as the core-team, that replaced thankful_for_today were [fluffypony](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=94840), [tacotime](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=19270), [NoodleDoodle](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=309703), [smooth](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=13813), othe, [David Latapie](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=81999), and [eizh](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=252925). At the end of 2015, the latter two core-team members [resigned](https://getmonero.org/2016/02/10/monero-missive-2015-year-in-review.html) from the core-team due to time constraints and were replaced by [luigi1111](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=171499) and [ArticMine](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=49057).

> Was the code just forked?

As far as I can see from the Github commit [history](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/commits/master?page=65), the stewards indeed forked the code over to a new Github repository and continued with that. The old repository of [thankful_for_today](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=233561%20thankful_for_today) can be found [here](https://github.com/bitmonero-project/bitmonero).

> What was the difference and disagreement?

This basically boils down to [thankful_for_today](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=233561%20thankful_for_today) playing the benevolent dictator and pushing changes which the community largely disagreed with. He also pushed changes without conferring with, or simply [ignoring](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=583449.msg10731078#msg10731078), the community. There are more extensive examples in the formal [write up](https://forum.getmonero.org/20/general-discussion/211/history-of-monero), under "the second renaissance".

> What exactly happened at this point in history?

There's a more elaborate and formal write up [here](https://forum.getmonero.org/20/general-discussion/211/history-of-monero). This write up also includes some kind of timeline.

Comment: Viewing from the outside, the forced move to enable merge-mining with Bytecoin was more than enough reason to fork away, it was not something bitmonero had when it was originally forked from Bytecoin by the TFT or whoever was the team at the time, it would have been a fundamental consensus breakage.